# Is it possible for garbage collector to clean up local variables declared within nested blocks inside same a function?

Tags: go, memory, scope, garbage-collection

Imagine I have code like this. Assume I am using some big heap-allocated structs

```golang
func working() {
  bigStruct1 := generateBigStructOne()
  bigStruct2 := generateBigStructTwo()

  // do something with bigStruct1, generate output1
  // do something with bigStruct2 and output1
}
```

If I were to scope the variables into nested blocks, could this be faster for GC? Can local variables from nested scopes that are now unreachable be immediately available to be freed by the GC ?

So:

```golang
func working() {
  var output1 *type
  {
    bigStruct1 := generateBigStructOne()
    // do something with bigStruct1, and now fill output1
  }

  // Is there a chance that bigStruct1 is cleaned by GC before the end of the function?
  ...
}
```

Tried a few resources but cannot find answer to this particular question

Comment: Memory occupied by an object can be reclaimed by GC as soon as it leaves scope. So, memory allocated in nested blocks of a function can be reclaimed. But there is no guarantee that it will.

Comment: If they are used only within function, then they may not even escape to the heap to be collected in the first place. If they do escape, then the block scope doesn’t really matter, as liveness is determined by a different representation of the program.

Comment: Are you experiencing performance problems related to the GC process? If not, don't worry about micro-optimizations like this. Not only are such micro-optimizations usually a waste of time, they often change as new Go versions are released. Focus on writing functional, readable code.

Comment: Replying to Jonathan: I started looking into this because I had an application loading big files, and sometimes it finished successfully or it went OOM - It also runs in an environment with constrained fixed memory resources. I made improvements elsewhere that fixed those issues. However I am looking into functions with this pattern of loading multiple big structs and wondering if scoping would bring benefits. Since we cannot determine for sure when GC will run, was hoping to find a definitive answer in one of the many Go resources :sweat-smile:  :) thanks